# Error building query which says "previous operations still waiting for clauses"

Tags: java, ormlite, query-builder

I am trying to query for 3 types of products, but I get this error:

```
The SQL statement has not been finished since there are previous operations 
    still waiting for clauses.
```

This is the code:

```
QueryBuilder<Product, UUID> queryBuilder = pDao.queryBuilder();
Where<Transaction, UUID> where = queryBuilder.where();
where.eq("state", Product.State.NEW)
          .and()
          .eq("type", Product.Type.DIGITAL)
          .or()                               -> I get the error here
          .eq("type", Product.Type.PHYSICAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SQL statement has not been finished since there are previous operations still waiting for clauses

Hrm.  I can't reproduce this and the test coverage on the `QueryBuilder` stuff is pretty good.  I've added a [similar test here](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/b71a4b68c3c3cb882d4b5908d91f2219cba67979#diff-abfd06154acf108935bf76613b9c9d78R488) which passes.

```
QueryBuilder<Foo, String> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
Where<Foo, String> where = qb.where();
where.eq(Foo.VAL_COLUMN_NAME, foo1.val)
        .and()
        .eq(Foo.STRING_COLUMN_NAME, foo1.stringField)
        .or()
        .eq(Foo.STRING_COLUMN_NAME, foo2.stringField);
```

I think that something else is going on.  Maybe additional `Where` calls are being made that aren't represented in your test?  If not, make sure you are running the 4.48 or 5.0 version.

You can also try to generate the query using the `and(...)` and `or(...)` with arguments:

```
 where.and(where.eq("state", Product.State.NEW),
           where.or(where.eq("type", Product.Type.DIGITAL),
                    where.eq("type", Product.Type.PHYSICAL)));
```

See the [docs on `QueryBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/docs/building-queries) for more.